# Trying to have error correction while prompting to run program again

Tags: c++, loops, error-handling

New to C++.  I have a homework program I am programming.  It is all but done, but our teacher wants us to add error catching to the program.

The issue arises in the code for asking the user to run again.  I use a while loop to monitor a variable until it changes.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char runAgainYN;

    while ( toupper(runAgainYN != 'N' ) {
        // Do some stuff here!

        cout << "Would you like to run again?";
        cin >> runAgainYN;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It keeps looping the program until runAgain is equal to 'N', then stops.  Now, I modified the program to utilize some error correction for the question about running the program again, to limit the user to only entering Y or N.  Here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char runAgainYN;
    bool runAgain = true;

    while ( runAgain ) {

        // Do some stuff here!

        bool validResponse = false;
        while ( !validResponse ) {
            cout << "Would you like to run the program again (Y/N): ";
            cin >> runAgainYN;
            if ( toupper(runAgainYN) == 'Y' ) {
                validResponse = true;
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else if ( toupper(runAgainYN) == 'N' ) {
                runAgain = false;
                validResponse = true;
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else {
                cout << "INVALID RESPONSE" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is where the problem arises.  If the user enters 'N', the program exits with code 0, and if the user enters anything but Y or N, the invalid response triggers and asks for the input again.  But, if the user enters Y, the program exits with code -1.  Huh?  I tried a different approach, with the same result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char runAgainYN;

    do {
        // Do some stuff here!

        bool validResponse = false;
        while ( !validResponse ) {
            cout << "Would you like to run the program again (Y/N): ";
            cin >> runAgainYN;
            if ( toupper(runAgainYN) == 'Y' ) {
                validResponse = true;
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else if ( toupper(runAgainYN) == 'N' ) {
                runAgain = false;
                validResponse = true;
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else {
                cout << "INVALID RESPONSE" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    while ( runAgain );

    return 0;
}
```

Any help guys?  Thanks!!!

OK, so it seems to be something in the actual program causing it.  Here's the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void cls();
void printLine( int length );
void showCurrency( double dv, int width = 14 );

int main() {

    string itemName[999][2];
    double itemPrice[999][3];
    double salesTotal = 0.0;
    double salesTax = 0.0;
    double totalTax = 0.0;
    double taxRate = 0.0;
    double grandTotal = 0.0;
    double test = 0.0;
    int numLines = 0;
    string readLine;
    string temp;
    ifstream fileIn;
    string menuHeader = "Sales Receipt from File";
    char runAgainYN;
    bool runAgain = true;

    do { // Loop until runAgain false

        // Open the file and count the number of lines, then close for next operation:
        fileIn.open("cost.txt");
        while (!fileIn.eof()) {
            fileIn >> temp;
            numLines++;
            temp = "";
        }
        fileIn.close();

        // Open the file and move the data into the arrays, then close:
        fileIn.open("cost.txt");
        for ( int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
            fileIn >> itemName[i][1] >> itemPrice[i][1];
        }
        fileIn.close();

        cls();

        numLines = numLines / 2;

        cout << "/";
        printLine(80);
        cout << "\\" << endl;
        cout << "|" << setw(81) << "|" << endl;
        cout << "|" << setw(41 + (menuHeader.length() / 2)) << menuHeader << setw(40 - (menuHeader.length() / 2)) << "|" << endl;
        cout << "|" << setw(81) << "|" << endl;
        cout << "\\";
        printLine(80);
        cout << "/" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter the sales tax percentage (ie for 6% enter 6): ";

        // Ask for taxRate and error check:
        while (!(cin >> taxRate)) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "INVALID RESPONSE" << endl << "Please enter a number: ";
        }
        cout << endl;

        salesTax = taxRate / 100; // Convert sales tax to percentage

        for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++ ) { // Set the running tax amounts
            itemPrice[i][2] = itemPrice[i][1] * salesTax;
            salesTotal = salesTotal + itemPrice[i][1];
            totalTax = totalTax + itemPrice[i][2];
        }

        //totalTax = salesTotal * salesTax; // Calculate tax

        grandTotal = salesTotal + totalTax; // Calculate grand total

        // Output:
        cls();

        cout << "/" << setfill('-') << setw(63) << "-" << "\\" << setfill(' ') << endl;
        cout << "|                        SALES RECEIPT                          |" << endl;
        cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(63) << "-" << "|" << setfill(' ') << endl;
        cout << "| " << left << setw(32) << "Sales item" << setw(13) << right << "Price" << setw(18) << "Tax |" << endl;
        cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(63) << "-" << "|" << setfill(' ') << endl;

        for ( int i = 0; i <= numLines - 1; ++i ){
            cout << "| " << left << setw(32) << itemName[i][1] << "$" << setw(12) << setprecision(2) << fixed << right << itemPrice[i][1] << setw(5) << "$" << setw(11) << itemPrice[i][2] << " |" << endl;
        }

        cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(63) << "-" << "|" << setfill(' ') << endl;

        cout << "| Total Sales" << setw(36);
        showCurrency(salesTotal);
        cout << " |" << endl;

        cout << "| Sales Tax (" << setprecision(0) << fixed << taxRate << "%)" << setw(33);
        showCurrency(totalTax);
        cout << " |" << endl;

        cout << "|" << setfill('-') << setw(63) << "-" << "|" << setfill(' ') << endl;

        cout << "| Grand Total" << setw(36);
        showCurrency(grandTotal);
        cout << " |"  << endl;

        cout << "\\" << setfill('-') << setw(63) << "-" << "/" << setfill(' ') << endl;

        cout << endl;

        // Clear vars and array for next run:
        salesTax = 0.0;
        totalTax = 0.0;
        salesTotal = 0.0;
        grandTotal = 0.0;
        memset(itemPrice, 0, sizeof(itemPrice));
        memset(itemName, 0, sizeof(itemName));

        // Ask if program is to be run again:
        bool validResponse = false;
        while ( !validResponse ) {
            cout << "Would you like to enter a new tax rate (Y/N): ";
            cin >> runAgainYN;
            if ( toupper(runAgainYN) == 'Y' ) {
                validResponse = true;
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else if ( toupper(runAgainYN) == 'N' ) {
                runAgain = false;
                validResponse = true;
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else {
                cout << "INVALID RESPONSE" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    while ( runAgain == true );

    return 0;

}

void printLine( int length ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        cout << "=";
    }
}

void cls() {
        // check OS and run correct clear screen (I do some of my coding in Linux :)
    #if (defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64))
        system("CLS");
    #elif (defined (LINUX) || defined (__linux__))
        system("clear");
    #endif
}

void showCurrency(double dv, int width){
    /* Credit where credit is due:
     * The following code snippet was found at https://arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html
     * Copyright © 2000, P. Lutus. All rights reserved.
     */

    const string radix = ".";
    const string thousands = ",";
    const string unit = "$";
    unsigned long v = (unsigned long) ((dv * 100.0) + .5);
    string fmt,digit;
    int i = -2;
    do {
        if(i == 0) {
            fmt = radix + fmt;
        }
        if((i > 0) && (!(i % 3))) {
            fmt = thousands + fmt;
        }
        digit = (v % 10) + '0';
        fmt = digit + fmt;
        v /= 10;
        i++;
    }
    while((v) || (i < 1));
    cout << unit << setw(width) << fmt.c_str();
}
```

And here is the contents of 'cost.txt':

```
Books 45.01
Pens 21.03
Pencils 10.90
Hats 50.00
Caps 800.00
Food 1.00
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug step by step with a debugger? Are you sure that it's not something in your "do some stuff here" that makes your program crash?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code (with `while ( runAgain ){...}`) works fine.

Comment: Can't reproduce on my desktop. What's your build/run environment?

Comment: In the last code quote I cannot find the definition of runAgain. Sure that you compiled that code as quoted?

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like i got it.  The file operations were within the do loop.  I moved them outside of the loop, and it all works.  Thanks!